# Docker can't use args in docker-compose (use args from .env)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, args

i want to pass some args i define in my .env file to the build process of my container

.env file:

```
OS_USER_UID=999
```

docker-compose:

```
  app:
    build: .
    args:
      - OS_USER_UID=$OS_USER_UID
```

but this alsways results in:

> Unsupported config option for services.app: 'args'

Why that? Can't i just use vars i define in .env as build variables?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) `args` should be defined inside `build` and with a `context` key to set the path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@samthegolden: Yes that helped, merci :)

```
app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - OS_USER
```